# Python Scrapy extract_first() documentation

Tags: python, scrapy

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133213/how-to-set-a-default-value-when-scrapy-selector-returns-none) question I learnt that a method `extract_first()` of scrapy `Selector` class instance can accept optional parameter `default` which is quite useful. However, I could not find any related [official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org) describing this feature. Even [Selector's reference](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=selector#topics-selectors-ref) under [Selector objects](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=selector#module-scrapy.selector) does not mention it. Maybe `extract_first()` has some more amazing features? Does anyone know know where the full description of `extract_first()` could be found?

Comment: did you try in code use `help(some_object.extract_first)` ? Sometimes it can display comment from source code with something useful

Comment: you can also use `import scrapy ; print(scrapy.__file__)` to find source code file and check it there.

Comment: in source code I found it is part of module `parsel` - more `import parsel ; help(parsel.SelectorList.extract_first)`

Comment: Thank you, guys. I haven't tried any of the options you proposed. I will keep it in my for the future cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can actually find it inside [the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) right after the phrase:

> A default return value can be provided as an argument, to be used instead of None:

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="not-exists"]/text()').extract_first(default='not-found')
'not-found'
```

Also remember that you can suggest documentation improvements on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/docs/topics/selectors.rst)

For now there isn't another amazing feature for `extract_first`, only setting default value if not found.