# How to set a default value when Scrapy selector with extract() returns None?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to yield the value of a tag that isn't always present in the pages that I scrape with Scrapy. I am using the `extract()` function rather than `extract_first()`. Therefore I cannot seem to set a default value, like suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133213/how-to-set-a-default-value-when-scrapy-selector-returns-none).

This doesn't work:

```
def parse(self, response):
        yield {
          'comments': response.css('[itemprop=commentCount]::attr(content)').extract(default=None)
          }
```

How can I set `None` as default when I want to use `extract()` rather than `extract_first()`?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Try this syntax:

```
{'comments': response.css('[itemprop=commentCount]::attr(content)').extract() or None}
```

If result of `response.css(CSS)` is empty list, then `None` will be assigned as value of `comments` key. Otherwise, actual value will be assigned

Answer (score 1):

`.extract()` yields the output as a list and `.extract_first()` yields a string.

```
response.xpath('xpath_of_the_component').extract_first(default="default_value").split()
```

This line of code will again convert the string to a list and set the default value, if not available.